# JS if-statement between a split string

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement

How can I place if statements between a split string? Obviously I can make it like that:

```
if(lang == 'eng'){
  var a_string = 'hello';
}else if(lang == 'ger'){
  var a_string = 'hallo';
}
```

but that's too long for some situations. What came in my mind was the following:

```
var lang = (e.g. 'ger' or 'eng');

var a_string = 'h' + if(lang == 'eng'){'e'}else if(lang == 'ger'){'a'} + 'llo';
```

Is there a way to write if statements between a split string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) :

> The **conditional (ternary) operator** is the only JavaScript operator that takes three operands. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the [if](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement.
>
> #### Syntax
>
> ```
> condition ? expr1 : expr2
> ```

```js
var lang = 'eng';
document.write('h' + (lang == 'eng' ? 'e' : lang == 'ger' ? 'a' : '') + 'llo' + '<br>');
lang = 'ger';
document.write('h' + (lang == 'eng' ? 'e' : lang == 'ger' ? 'a' : '') + 'llo');
```

An other solution with [Logical AND (&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) and [Logical OR (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) could be

```js
var lang = 'eng';
document.write('h' + (lang == 'eng' && 'e' || lang == 'ger' && 'a' || '') + 'llo' + '<br>');
lang = 'ger';
document.write('h' + (lang == 'eng' && 'e' || lang == 'ger' && 'a' || '') + 'llo');
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could store your key/value pairs in an object and then you don't need to check the value of `lang` directly. This might be helpful if you need to re-use the same values multiple times.

```
var greetings = {}
greetings.eng = 'e'
greetings.ger = 'a'

var lang = "eng"

"h" + greetings[lang] + "llo" // 'hello'

lang = "ger"

"h" + greetings[lang] + "llo" // 'hallo'
```